# Jquery-Stop setInterval after animate function

Tags: jquery

The idea is for the div to move in clockwise direction in a loop using setinterval after the user clicks Start button. When the user clicks on Stop, the setInterval should stop and go back to its original position. I could not get the thing to stop. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;

  $('#start').click(function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginLeft': '200px'
      }, 2000)
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginTop': '200px'
      }, 2000)
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginLeft': '10px'
      }, 2000)
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginTop': '0px'
      }, 2000)

    }, 50);

  });
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 237px;
  height: 263px;
}

div {
  margin: 7px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

div.newcolor {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<div id="animate"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, take into account that the variable timer is outside of the scope of the event attached in "stop". Also, you must take into account that when you use the method animate you are inserting into a queue the animation every 50 ms (because you are using the setInterval), so you must use the stop(true) that clear that queue.

Take a look into the documentation and the example of it:
https://api.jquery.com/stop/

```js
var timer;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#start').click(function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginLeft': '200px'
      }, 2000)
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginTop': '200px'
      }, 2000)
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginLeft': '10px'
      }, 2000)
      $("#animate").animate({
        'marginTop': '0px'
      }, 2000)

    }, 50);

  });
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
  $("#animate").stop(true);
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 237px;
  height: 263px;
}

div {
  margin: 7px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

div.newcolor {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<div id="animate"></div>
```